Adaptive volume in Android phone based on the level of background noise
I would like to know if it is possible to programme an adaptive volume function in Android phone and how demanding that would be. The goal would be programmatically adjust volume of white noise or music played on the phone via bluetooth speakers based on the level of changing background noise. We have a road close to our garden and we currently play white noise when we spend time in the garden. The traffic is not steady and it would be nice to lower the volume when there is no cars and raise the volume again when needed. In essence the purpose would be to create some kind of very crude adaptive/reactive "counter sound" or "sound mask" with modified mobile phone and bluetooth speakers.
Additional beneficial features would be the possibility to adjust the level of volume adaptation and maybe the delay/speed of volume raising and lowering.
I'm not a programmer but I would like to know if this modification would be a realistic option to achieve the described goal. And if this is theoretically possible then it would be nice to know how demanding this would be if I would like to find somebody to modify a mobile phone in this way. Rough estimate of the amount of work needed would be nice. And of course there is the chance that this modification already exists but I have limited knowledge how to search this.
I'm aware that some Google Pixel phones have some type of adaptive volume feature but I have understood that it is only function on the phone speaker itself and not working with headphones or external speakers. I believe also Google Nest Audio -smart speaker has this type of feature. I have not been able to test this product and it has no way to adjust this.
Other options would be a professional level audio matrix processor based audio system. I have been quoted ca. 2000 euros for this type of set up but it would also be physically bigger system and lot more difficult to set up and weather proof. Also the price tag feels high at this point.

The hardest part of this would likely be not picking up your own audio output as increased background noise.

I think to phone (as an input/microphone) could be inside the house on the window sill facing the road. It would pick up the changes in ambient noise from there. In the backgargen there would be bluetooth speakers (as output) and the sound from those would not affect the phone. I hope the bluetooth range would be sufficient. I found an android app called "automate" which might be able to solve this.
